# Last 10 transaction query Sql and springboot

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot

```
public List<Transaction> getLastTenTransactions(Long accountNo){
        List<Transaction> transactions = transactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(accountNo);
        return  transactions;
    }
```

i am using this function(getLastTenTransactions()) in my service to find the last 10 transaction from my transactions table, based on the account no.

but this particular query throws me an error. can someone help identify the right query.
please find attached my entity class.

```
package com.system.bank.model;



import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name= "Transaction" )
public class Transaction {

        private Long accountNo;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long transactionId;
        private  String getTransactionValue; //credit or debit
        private Date timeStamp;
        private double transactionAmount;

    public Transaction(Long accountNo, String getTransactionValue,Double transactionAmount) {
        this.accountNo = accountNo;
        // this.transactionId = transactionId;
        this.getTransactionValue = getTransactionValue;
        //this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.transactionAmount=transactionAmount;
    }

    public Transaction() {
        super();
        Date date =new Date();
        this.timeStamp = date;
    }

    public double getTransactionAmount() {
        return transactionAmount;
    }

    public void setTransactionAmount(double transactionAmount) {
        this.transactionAmount = transactionAmount;
    }



    public Long getAccountNo() {
        return accountNo;
    }

    public void setAccountNo(Long accountNo) {
        this.accountNo = accountNo;
    }

    public Long getTransactionId() {
        return transactionId;
    }

    public void setTransactionId(Long transactionId) {
        this.transactionId = transactionId;
    }

    public String getGetTransactionValue() {
        return getTransactionValue;
    }

    public void setGetTransactionValue(String getTransactionValue) {
        this.getTransactionValue = getTransactionValue;
    }

    public Date getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(Date timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }
}
```

This is the error received when i run. my application.

**Error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bankController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'bankService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bankServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'transactionRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionRepository' defined in com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(java.lang.Long)! No property orderBytimeStampDesc found for type Long! Traversed path: Transaction.accountNo.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(java.lang.Long)! No property orderBytimeStampDesc found for type Long! Traversed path: Transaction.accountNo.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:732) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:414) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
    at com.system.bank.BankApplication.main(BankApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'bankServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'transactionRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionRepository' defined in com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(java.lang.Long)! No property orderBytimeStampDesc found for type Long! Traversed path: Transaction.accountNo.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(java.lang.Long)! No property orderBytimeStampDesc found for type Long! Traversed path: Transaction.accountNo.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionRepository' defined in com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(java.lang.Long)! No property orderBytimeStampDesc found for type Long! Traversed path: Transaction.accountNo.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(java.lang.Long)! No property orderBytimeStampDesc found for type Long! Traversed path: Transaction.accountNo.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(java.lang.Long)! Reason: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(java.lang.Long)! No property orderBytimeStampDesc found for type Long! Traversed path: Transaction.accountNo.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(java.lang.Long)! No property orderBytimeStampDesc found for type Long! Traversed path: Transaction.accountNo.
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException.create(QueryCreationException.java:101) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:106) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1056) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:364) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:322) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:230) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:114) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:328) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.system.bank.repository.TransactionRepository.findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(java.lang.Long)! No property orderBytimeStampDesc found for type Long! Traversed path: Transaction.accountNo.
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:113) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:254) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:102) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property orderBytimeStampDesc found for type Long! Traversed path: Transaction.accountNo.
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:437) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:447) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:470) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:413) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:348) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:331) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:249) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:383) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:384) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]
    ... 75 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 0
```

TransactionRepository.java

```
package com.system.bank.repository;

import com.system.bank.model.Transaction;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface TransactionRepository extends CrudRepository<Transaction,Long> {
    public List<Transaction> findFirst10ByaccountNoOrderBytimeStampDesc(Long accountNo);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the repository add like this. You can create a model class. The native query true actually lets you use any native query that you have configured

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM ScemaName.TableA WHERE TableA.USERID = ?1 AND TableA.PASSWORD = ?2",nativeQuery = true)
        TableA loginUser(String userId,String password);
```

Also for further idea you can read this blog
[Native query blog](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)